# Create a user session with a usergroup in TYPO3 v12

Tags: authentication, cookies, typo3

In TYPO3 v10 we could create a user and simulate a usergroup with the following code:

```
            $sessionData = array_merge([
                'uid' => 0,
                'usergroup' => $this->settings['userGroupUid'],
                'status' => 'login'
            ], $loginResponse->getData());
 
            $this->getFeUser()->dontSetCookie = false;
            $this->getFeUser()->createSessionId();
            $this->getFeUser()->setAndSaveSessionData(Client::SESSION_KEY, $sessionData);
```

In TYPO3 v12 createSessionId was removed. How can we do this in TYPO3 v12.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Changelog on https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/11.0/Deprecation-93023-ReworkedSessionHandling.html - this describes possible migration paths.

Something like this might work already and actually saves you some lines (untested):

```
        $sessionData = array_merge([
            'uid' => 0,
            'usergroup' => $this->settings['userGroupUid'],
            'status' => 'login'
        ], $loginResponse->getData());

        $this->getFeUser()->initializeUserSessionManager();
        $this->getFeUser()->setAndSaveSessionData(Client::SESSION_KEY, $sessionData);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this dose not work. The group is not simulated.

Comment: Can you specify more context and make this reproducible code I can try?

Comment: I can try. We use an external authentification. But when the user is logged in, we want to give her or him a fe usergroup, so that we can manage the access to some content and pages in TYPO3.